# UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification not always called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

When developing an app for iOS, I've encountered a strange problem.
To be precise, it's about a chat app. Inside the chat view controller, the message input box should stick to the keyboard when it appears. I've got that one covered with the `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification`.
However, the problem is that this notification is not called when I change from the default keyboard to the emoji keyboard, which is slightly taller, the notification is not called (I'm leading both `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` to the same selector, none of them is called, I've tested it by doing a `NSLog` and setting a breakpoint). That results in the keyboard overlapping the message box. I made some screenshots to visualize the problem.
[Default keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAIfL.png)
[Emoji keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YILKH.png)

I've tested it on an iPhone X and on the iPhone 8 Plus Simulator, but there, everything's fine because the auto-completion bar makes up the difference between the two keyboards.

Am I implementing the wrong notification? How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Is it necessary for you to figure out a solution with keyboard notification or alternate solution would be fine ?

Comment: An alternate solution would be fine too. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it seems like this was an actual bug in iOS 11. It seems to be fixed in iOS 11.2.6.